# Enabling and disabling scrolling on pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages and on one page I need to have disabled scrolling and on the other page enabled, but when I try to do that with jQuery the whole screen shakes and it is almost impossible to scroll.

This is how I did it in the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
  if (window.location.pathname = '/all') {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
  } else {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

Is there an other way which would work to do the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the screen shakes'? The only thing I can think would cause any change in dimensions is the scrollbar disappearing.

Comment: I have images on the page where I am disabling the scroll and some columns with images are shaking horizontally

Comment: Yes - that's caused by the scroll bar disappearing. There's not much you can do about that as you disabled scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the single equals sign in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preventDefault` on scroll events.

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', (e) => e.preventDefault())
```

If you also need to block down and up keys you also need to capture the keypress event on the `$(window)` and `preventDefault` them.